# WSO2 an Open Source Enterprise Service Bus (ESB)

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am new to this can  u please guide me which is good site to start WSO2 ESB Open Source Enterprise Service Bus (ESB)  proxy services

Answer (score 0):

[WSO2 Docs](http://docs.wso2.org/) is the best place to get started.

You can refer [WSO2 ESB 4.7.0](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB470/Enterprise+Service+Bus+Documentation), which is the latest WSO2 ESB release.

Please go through the [samples](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB470/Samples).

You have few things [to do](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB470/ESB+Samples+Setup) before trying samples and then you can go through [Proxy Service samples](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB470/Proxy+Service+Samples).

I hope this helps!